# Использование mono на Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, sqlite, mono

Есть консольное приложение на C#, на Windows все благополучно работает, но появилась нужда поставить это приложение на сервер под управлением Ubuntu Server 18.04 x86_64. После запуска команды `mono RHBot.exe` выводится такая ошибка:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods:sqlite3_config_none (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized () [0x0001c] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize (System.String className) [0x00026] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.Boolean parseViaFramework) [0x00046] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection:.ctor (string)
  at VKBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0006e] in <69f24e52cda4494abdf8dac4c5408e44>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: SQLite.Interop.dll
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods:sqlite3_config_none (System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized () [0x0001c] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize (System.String className) [0x00026] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString, System.Boolean parseViaFramework) [0x00046] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in <226287aa71b9481b9dd405c36cfaba76>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection:.ctor (string)
  at VKBot.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0006e] in <69f24e52cda4494abdf8dac4c5408e44>:0
```

Хотя `SQLite.Interop.dll` лежит в папках `x86` и `x64`. Что делать?

Comment: Собрать приложении как 32 битное, или наоборот, как 64 битное - формат файла не совпадает

Comment: @NewView Такую же ошибку выдает

Comment: Путь 1: полазить в моно, с выхлопом версии Net фреймворка и собрать на винде с таким же Net. Путь 2: перенести исходники на моно и собрать там.

Comment: @NewView вот tracelog запуска mono https://pastebin.com/mMC0k19N может поможет

Comment: Версия sql сборки 32/64 ? Определиться с платформой и все аккуратно проверить на соответствие. И все же проще собрать на моно, если и будут ошибки, то по ходу..

Comment: По всей видимости, у вас `SQLite.Interop.dll` для работы в виндовом окружении, а вам нужна эта же библиотека, но собранная для работы в линуксе.

Comment: @Bulson А где ее можно найти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - попробовать запустить именно на dotNet, который есть под Ubuntu.

Comment: Не подскажете как запустить? dotnet утсановил, а что дальше?

Comment: Если верно помню, то dotnet prog.exe

Comment: Выдает такую ошибку: `A fatal error was encountered. The library 'libhostpolicy.so' required to execute the application was not found in '/home/bot/bot/bin/Release/'.`